# Filtering Files with prefix as well as age of file

Tags: java, file, filtering, apache-commons, prefix

I am trying to retrieve all the files that start with `"Sample"` and also all those that were created/modified at the same time as that of given timestamp or before the time stamp. I have to get the latest file from these.

I could filter the files with the prefix but i am not sure of how to add one more filter i.e. `timestamp`.

I initially used `LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE` but it checks for all files not according to `timestamp`. So to do these i need filtering on `timestamp` as well.
I have an idea that `AgeFileFilter` and `PrefixFileFilter` classes of apache commons will help me but i am unable put together both the classes.

How do i achieve this?

Below is my code

```
public void searchFiles(File path) {
    FilenameFilter prefix = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File directory, String filename) {
             return filename.startsWith("Sample");
        }
    };

    SimpleDateFormat dateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    File[] files1 = path.listFiles(prefix);
    Arrays.sort(files1, LastModifiedFileComparator.LASTMODIFIED_REVERSE);
    System.out.println("\nThe latest file is: "+files1[0]+ " & is updated on: " + dateTime.format(files1[0].lastModified()));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a filter that can compare filenames and modification times too.
`FilenameFilter` cannot do this, but `FileFilter` can, for example:

```
FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().startsWith("Sample") && pathname.lastModified() > LASTMODIFIED_LIMIT;
    }
};
```

The same thing can be written shorter with a lambda:

```
FileFilter filter = pathname -> pathname.getName().startsWith("Sample")
        && pathname.lastModified() > LASTMODIFIED_LIMIT;
```

Comment: hope i didn't confuse you, i edited code, path is the directory in which i have to list files based on filters. Now can you recheck.

Comment: @Rvmems that doesn't change anything, my answer stands all the same